# using a sql request in spark sql error in execution

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I try to execute this query in pyspark i get all the time error. I have looked everywhere but I don't know or it doesn't work if someone can help me. the goal of this request is to update a new column that I will later create called temp_ok :
this my code:

```
CASE WHEN _temp_ok_calculer='non' AND Operator level 2 ="XXX" OR  Operator level 2= "AAA" AND Auto Cleaning criteria !="YYY" Auto Cleaning criteria <> "AA"  AND Workstation Type = "Chaine A" THEN 'ok' ELSE CASE WHEN _temp_ok_calculer='ok' THEN 'ok' ELSE 'ko' END END
```

My table contains this columns: _temp_ok_calculer,Operator level 2, Auto Cleaning criteria, Workstation Type

Comment: Looks like you're just missing an `AND`: `AND Auto Cleaning criteria !="YYY" AND Auto Cleaning criteria <> "AA" `

Comment: Thank you i correct the messing AND but the error still exists

Comment: You also have an `ELSE CASE` towards the end that should just be the second `WHEN`, plus what David notes in his answer about the back-tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark SQL uses back-tick ` for delimiters, and [identifiers](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-identifier.html) with spaces in them must be delimited identifiers in SQL.  So

```
CASE WHEN _temp_ok_calculer='non' AND `Operator level 2` ="XXX" OR . . .
```